# Return a cell based on certain condition

Tags: ios, uitableview

For example I have this in my code:

```
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    if ([advisorData sharedInstance].vicePresident == nil) {
        return cell;
    }
     else{
    _advisorCell.positionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vice President"];
    _advisorCell.nameLabel.text = [advisorData sharedInstance].vicePresident;
    _advisorCell.emailLabel.text = [advisorData sharedInstance].vpEmail;
    _advisorCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;;
        return _advisorCell;}
    }
```

I need to return a cell based on a condition. But I get an error -'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'- I don't understand why I keep getting this error because I am returning a cell. I tried without the else statement as well.

Comment: You've left out all the important parts. Show the whole method.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you never initialized `_advisorCell` and it's `nil`. In that case, all the configuration you're doing does nothing, and you're just returning `nil`. Alternately, the same might be true for `cell`.